# Dynamic h:inputtext to backing Bean Array in jsf [ClassCastException]

Tags: java, jsf

I'm using JSF 2.0
I have a problem to set Values of inputTexts to a table of double.

I can do this :

```html
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.table[0]}" />
```

But, I would like to do it in a loop like that:

```html
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="#{myBean.inputsNumber}">              
    <h:inputText  value="#{myBean.table[i]}" />     <br/>            
</c:forEach>   
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.calculate}" value="Calculate" /> 
Result: #{myBean.result}
```

Here is my backing bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {

    private double[] table;
    private double result;

    public MyBean() {
        table = new double[100];
    }

    public void calculate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            result += table[i];
        }
    }

    public double[] getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public int getInputsNumber() {
        return table.length;
    }

    public double getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

I tried to bind all components to an array of `HtmlInputText`, but I could not solve it.
i got this exception : ClassCastException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. The `<c:forEach end>` is inclusive. You need to take 1 off from it, otherwise you end up with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when submitting.

   ```html
   <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="#{myBean.inputsNumber - 1}">
   ```

   A better approach is however to just iterate over the array itself and get the index by `varStatus`.

   ```html
   <c:forEach items="#{myBean.table}" varStatus="loop">
       <h:inputText value="#{myBean.table[loop.index]}" />
   </c:forEach>
   ```

   ---
2. A double in EL is treated as `Double`, not as `double`. So you need `Double[]` instead of `double[]`, otherwise you end up with `ClassCastException` when submitting.

   ```
   private Double[] table;
   ```

Comment: This is the solution for my problem : private Double[] table , i had ClassCastException , thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. In the future questions, it'd be more helpful for others if you elaborate in detail which problems/exceptions exactly you're facing. Exceptions are not thrown for decoration, but they actually tell something about the cause of the problem and thus indirectly also about the solution.